# Password Validation program

Tags: python

Please I need to insert some sort code to ask the user again to input the password again and also print invalid password when the validation criteria are not met. Also, I would need a review on this code to see what changes I should make. Thanks

```
x = input("Enter your password: ")

while not 6 <= len(x) <= 16:
    if len(x) < 6:
        print("Password should be minimum of 6 characters")
        break
    elif len(x) > 16:
        print("Password shouldn't exceed 16 characters")
        break
else:
    if not re.search("[a-z]", x):
        print("Password must include lower case")
    elif not re.search("[A-Z]", x):
        print("Password must include upper case")
    elif not re.search("[0-9]", x):
        print("Password must include number")
    elif not re.search("[$#@]", x):
        print("Password must include special character")
    elif re.search("\s", x):
        print("Password must not include space")
    else:
        print("Password Validated")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working code:

```
import re
while 1:
    x = input("Enter your password: ")
    if len(x) < 6:
        print("Password should be minimum of 6 characters")
    elif len(x) > 16:
        print("Password shouldn't exceed 16 characters")
    else:
        if not re.search("[a-z]", x):
            print("Password must include lower case")
        elif not re.search("[A-Z]", x):
            print("Password must include upper case")
        elif not re.search("[0-9]", x):
            print("Password must include number")
        elif not re.search("[$#@]", x):
            print("Password must include special character")
        elif re.search("\s", x):
            print("Password must not include space")
        else:
            print("Password Validated")
            break
```

This is what it returns:

```
Enter your password: 11111
Password should be minimum of 6 characters
Enter your password: 11111111
Password must include lower case
Enter your password: 1111111l
Password must include upper case
Enter your password: 1111111Ll
Password must include special character
Enter your password: 11111Ll#
Password Validated
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a condition at the start that should be :

```
 while (True)
```

This means it will repeat while it's true and then stop when it's false.Also, add **continue**  after every condition so that it will not stop and **break** at the last condition.

For example:

```
while True:

x = input("Enter your password: ")

while not 6 <= len(x) <= 16:
    if len(x) < 6:
        print("Password should be minimum of 6 characters")
    elif len(x) > 16:
        print("Password shouldn't exceed 16 characters")
        continue
...
.
..
.
.
.
break //at the end so that if the condition is not met it will break.
```